# Not able to set theme in zshrc after alf plugin installation

Tags: macos, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I recently installed `Alf` plugin to `oh-my-zshrc` and after the installation, the default theme is set to `pure` and even after setting `ZSH_THEME=soirn` in .zshrc file the changes are not taking place. Any suggestions on setting the desired theme are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After editing theme, you need to **save** the *source* file and **reload** it.

- save source file;
  **ctrl+x**
- Reload source file;
  **source .zshrc**

Comment: It has been done but no use. as soon as saving the source file, I reloaded the .zshrc file it didn't work . @Aashish

Comment: Are you sure you have the theme installed in local machine? Some themes need to be downloaded ; all themes aren't provided by zshrc